# checkbox value as boolean can't access the database - android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I made a form which should be filled by a user in my application, some of the variables numeric and some boolean , the data thats coming from the user is going to db that I've created. 
I made the checkBox's boolean(true/false) , and edittext's numeric (int) . For some reason, it gives me an exception, and a lot of crashes.

Here are some of my code :

```
public void addArea(View view) {
    Area area = new Area();

    SQLiteDatabase areasDB = openOrCreateDatabase("AREA_DATABASE.sqlite", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    areasDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS areas_table(name TEXT, smoking_area INTEGER" +
            "outside_or_inside INTEGER, num_of_tables INTEGER" +
            "num_of_diners INTEGER)");

    area.setName(areaName.getText().toString());

    name = areaName.getText().toString();

    outside = chkOut.isChecked();
    inside = chkIn.isChecked();
    smokingArea = chkSmoking.isChecked();
    Integer.parseInt(numOFTables = editNumTables.getText().toString());
    Integer.parseInt(numOFDiners = maxDiners.getText().toString());


    if (areaName.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
            editNumTables.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
            maxDiners.getText().toString().isEmpty()){


        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Area_creating_activity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Oops,");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You forgot to fill something");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();



    } else {

        areasDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO areas_table VALUES('" + name + "','" + outside + "','" + inside+ "','" + smokingArea + "','"
                                                            + numOFTables + "','" + numOFDiners + "')");

        AlertDialog alertSucsess = new AlertDialog.Builder(Area_creating_activity.this).create();
        alertSucsess.setTitle("Congrats,");
        alertSucsess.setMessage(name + " Has been created");
        alertSucsess.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Zone.class));

            }
        });

        alertSucsess.show();

    }

    areasDB.close();
}
```

one of the errors i get :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3846)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mika.waiter.Area_creating_activity.addArea(Area_creating_activity.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Learn how to use database in Android [here](http://androhub.com/android-sqlite-database/).

Comment: one of the objects you use in `addArea()`, carries value `null`, which line is line 58?

Comment: @Sander outside = chkOut.isChecked();
        inside = chkIn.isChecked();

Comment: That means that you need to add `chkOut = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.[whatever the id is])`. And for chkIn as well.

Comment: it worked! but now it gives me another exeption: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3846)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

Comment: You should make a new question for that. Btw the duplicate mark is ridiculous